# How to boot RHEL5 into failsafe mode from GRUB?

Tags: linux, grub, failsafe

I'm locked out of a Red Hat Linux 5 machine and need to "break in" to reset the root password.  I've done this before by interrupting GRUB and putting the machine in failsafe to get to root, but I can not remember the details.  Once I stop GRUB, what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Booting:

- Use the arrow keys to select the kernel to boot
- Hit <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the command line
- Append `init=/bin/bash` to that line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>b</kbd> to boot

Once booted:

- `mount -o remount,rw /`
- `passwd`